# How to count all the possibilities of NQueens?

Tags: java, function, methods, boolean

So the code below is an NQueens program that gives the correct true or false return of whether NQueens is possible with the given variable (ie if it is 3, then is it possible for a 3x3 board). What I'm having trouble with is finding out how many different possibilities there are for it. For example in a 4x4 there are 2 possibilities, so it should return true, (which it already does) and 2. I am not sure where to put this counter method or change the code so that it keeps going after one possibility.

Any advice?

```
package model;

public class NQueensModel
{
    private int myNumsQueen;
    private int myPossibilities;
    private boolean[][] myBoard;
    private static NQueensModel myModel = new NQueensModel(4);

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println(myModel.solvePuzzle());


    }
    public NQueensModel(int nQueens)
    {
        myNumsQueen = nQueens;
        myPossibilities=0;
        myBoard = new boolean[myNumsQueen][myNumsQueen];
    }
    public boolean solvePuzzle()
    {
        return this.solvePuzzle(0);
    }
    private boolean solvePuzzle(int ncolumn)
    {
        if(ncolumn>myNumsQueen-1)
        {

            return true;
        }
        int i;

        for( i =0; i<myNumsQueen;i++)
        {

            if(this.isSafeMove(i, ncolumn)==true)
            {

                this.placeQueen(i,ncolumn);
                System.out.println(i + " " + ncolumn);
                if(this.solvePuzzle(ncolumn+1)==true)
                {
                    return true;

                }
                this.removeQueen(i, ncolumn);
            }

        }

        return false;

    }
    private boolean isSafeMove(int row, int col)
    {

         if(this.checkLowerDiag(row, col)==true ||this.checkUpperDiag(row, col)==true ||this.checkLeft(row,col)==true)
         {
             return false;
         }
        else
        {

            return true;
        }


    }
    private boolean checkUpperDiag(int row, int col)
    {    
        if(row==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=row, j = col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--)
            {
                if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean checkLowerDiag(int row, int col)
    {

        if(col==0 )
        {           
            return false;             
        }
        else
        {

            for(int i = row, j = col; i<myNumsQueen && j>=0;  i++, j--)
            {
                if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    return true;

                }


            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean checkLeft(int row, int col)
    {
        if(col==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int i = col; i>=0; i--)
            {
                if(myBoard[row][i]==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
    private boolean placeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = true;
        return true;
    }
    private boolean removeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = false;
        return false;
    }
//    public String toString()
//    {
//        
//    }
}
```

Comment: In the moment you detect it is a valid solution, add one to a counter field in our `NQueensModel` class. Looks like this happens inside `if(ncolumn>myNumsQueen-1)` inside `private boolean solvePuzzle(int ncolumn)` method. Also, instead of stopping the algorithm after finding the first solution, just let your code continue running.

Comment: How would I let it continue running?

Comment: From my last comment: *instead of stopping the algorithm after finding the first solution, just let your code continue running*. So, instead of returning `true` or whatever you do to stop the recursive algorithm after finding an answer, just let the code continue with the algorithm. You know your code better than us, so spot this line of code and remove/comment it. Looks like it is the `return true;` inside `if(this.solvePuzzle(ncolumn+1)==true)` in `private boolean solvePuzzle(int ncolumn)` (but this is a guess only from a quick review of your code).

Answer (score 0):

Below is some sudo code of one possible solution. It keeps a running count of all the valid solutions you have discovered thus far. When a new solution is discovered you add it to the count and return. This will complete until all possible solutions are discovered.

```
public int solvePuzzle(int solutionCount, int col){
   if(isValidSolution())
      return solutionCount + 1;
   else if(solutionFails())
      return solutionCount;
   else {
      for(/*Every position you want to check in this col*/){
         solutionCount = solvePuzzle(solutionCount, col + 1);
      }
      return solutionCount;
   }
}
```

Comment: The above code was not complete, it also needs all logic to add and remove queens. In the for loop you need to make sure you add before and remove after the call to solvePuzzle(). Also the solutionFails() helper method should only be true if we are in the last column.